# python-requests sending wrong multi-part payload

Tags: python, http, flask, python-requests

I'm trying to use the `requests` package to send a multi-part POST request.

Here is the code:

```
with open("small-car.png", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_image = "data:image/png;base64,%s" % base64.b64encode(image_file.read())

files = {'img': encoded_image}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

On the server side, I'm relying on the below flask code to decode it:

```
    data = request.form.to_dict()
```

However, `data` is always `{}`. A peak with wireshark show the following:

[image]

This seems wrong. The correct header shouldn't include the `filename=xxx` part I believe.

Is there a way to tweak `requests` to do the correct thing here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the following:

```
    data = {'file': files}
    response = requests.put(url=url, data=data)
```

Also, instead of using wireshark you could add a trace in your flask code (`import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`) and examine what is being posted within Python.

Answer (score 0):

im pretty sure your headers are ok.
in flash receive the files seperatly

check this out: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    file = request.files['file']
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude the `filename` part just do the following:

```
data = {'img': ('', encoded_image)}
requests.post(url, files=data)
```

The first element of the tuple will be taken as the filename and since it's empty, it will be excluded.